# How to use Yii2 Sluggable Behavior?

Tags: php, url, routes, yii2, slug

I have defined this behavior as per documentation instructions.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
        ],
    ];
}
```

In my config url manager I have defined custom rule like this: `example.com/article/1`

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'article/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'article/view',
    ],
],
```

My view action is:

```
public function actionView($id, $slug = null)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

In my index view file I am generating URL to view action like this :  `Url::to(['article/view', 'id' => $model->id, 'slug' => $model->slug])`

I would like to output my article title in url like this: `example.com/article/1/My-first-post`

But I am not getting title in URL.

Soju said that slug is a database attribute. I have created new column in my article table called slug and it is varchar 1024. But I am still not getting slug generated in URL. My URL is: `example.com/article/1`

What is wrong ? Thanks

**EDIT**: I have updated my code to insert title value into slug column in my article table. Now I get slug working but I do not get SEO URL-s. I get this: `article/1/First+Article`, and I would like `article/1/First-Article`.

I have tried with:

```
return [
    TimestampBehavior::className(),
    [
        'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
        'attribute' => 'title',
        'value' => function ($event) {
            return str_replace(' ', '-', $this->slug);
        }
    ],
];
```

This doesn't work either: `return str_replace(' ', '-', $this->slug);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the following `urlManager` rule :

```
'article/<id:\d+>/<slug>' => 'article/view',
```

And build url in your views like this :

```
\yii\helpers\Url::to(['article/view', 'id'=>$model->id, 'slug'=>$model->slug])
```

You could also add helpers in your model :

```
public function getRoute()
{
    return ['article/view', 'id'=>$this->id, 'slug'=>$this->slug];
}

public function getUrl()
{
    return \yii\helpers\Url::to($this->getRoute());
}
```

And then simply use `$model->url` in your views.

Comment: If I do it like that, I will get this url: `article/view?id=1`, slug is not used.

Comment: Of course I did, and it is not working. Have you configured sluggable behavior like I did in post ?

Comment: "it is not working" is not enough, please add details : error message or else

Comment: I already told you that url is article/view?id=1, it does not have slug in it. There are no error messages. URL does not output slug

Comment: `Url::to(['article/view', 'id' => $model->id, 'slug' => $model->slug])`

Comment: Sluggable Behaviour is defined in my Article Model like this: `public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        TimestampBehavior::className(),
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'value' => function ($event) {
                return str_replace(' ', '-', $this->title);
            }
        ],
    ];
}`

Comment: actionVeiw is : `public function actionView($id, $slug = null)
{
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}`

Comment: And in Article model, there is slug attribute defined:  `public $slug;`

Comment: Please update your question instead of adding comments... And slug is a database attribute, it should not be declared like this.

Comment: Did you remove `public $slug` in your article model ?

Comment: Now I did, and I get this url generated: `article/1`, and when I click on link to go to view page I get this error: `Page not found. `

Comment: What do you mean ? Update what, where ? When I create some article, I need to copy title to slug ? Right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72227/discussion-between-soju-and-anita).