# Yii2 Dynamic URL Routing Rules

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing

I want to set `Dynamic Routing` for url in Cms pages in yii2.
When i add Cms page i will add page alias aboutus,faq,management etc , these alias will saved in db .

When i give URL rule static it will work ,[check code below]

```
'urlManager' => [               
            'showScriptName' => false,  
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,  
            //'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules'=>array(
'aboutus'=>'cms/index/1',
'faq'=>'cms/index/2',
'termacondition'=>'cms/index/3',
'management'=>'cms/index/4',
),
        ],
```

But i want add url rule in dynamically .

I need add all dynamic page alias in config/main.php  URL rule in yii2
Please help me.

Comment: What is the model class for your alias table ?

Comment: Posted an answer , check if its working in your case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can edit you routing rules during bootstrapping process.

First create bootstrapping class by implementing  `yii\base\BootstrapInterface`

Under Your components directory create a file called DynaRoute.php

```
<?php

 namespace app\components;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;
 use app\models\Cms;  // assuming Cms is the Model class for table containing aliases
 class DynaRoute implements BootstrapInterface
 {
     public function bootstrap($app)
     {

        $cmsModel = Cms::find()
            ->all(); // customize the query according to your need
        routeArray = [];
        foeach($cmsModel as $row) { // looping through each cms table row
            $routeArray[$row->alias] = 'YOUR_ORIGINAL_URL'; // Adding rules to array on by one
        }
        $app->urlManager->addRules($routeArray);// Append new rules to original rules
}
```

}

Now in your configuration file (web.php in config folder) in `$config` array add above class under bootstrap option

```
'bootstrap' => [
    .... // other bootstrap options 
    'app\components\DynaRoute', // add this line 
],
```

Comment: I am intergated above code all going fine , But one issue in Dynaroute.php   $routeArray[$row->alias] = '/cms/'.$row->alias;                                            when i integated this its not working  .

Comment: If i add static orginal URL it will work                                              $routeArray[$row->alias] = '/customer/index';

Comment: Also share the url your are getting now , and the expected url

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ck_arjun's answer, you can pass parameter to route as an ID.
For example, if you want redirect "*/aboutus*" to "*/site/page/id/2*".

Replace:

```
$routeArray[$row->alias] = 'YOUR_ORIGINAL_URL'
```

in

```
$routeArray[] = ['class' => 'yii\web\UrlRule', 'pattern' => $row->alias, 'route' => $row->route, 'defaults' => ['id' => $row->id]];
```